# Automation tool for testing python code and javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Does anyone know any free automation testing tool for unit testing python code and javascript?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.  What kind(s) of testing are you talking about?  Have you done any looking around yourself because I know both have unit test frameworks that Google could tell you about.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to compose a number of testing frameworks together. Our team uses nose http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/ as pointed out by @Arbie.

We use nose to also run selenium http://seleniumhq.org/ tests with the python driver which is really the only way I know of to effectively test javascript that manipulates the DOM. Although I have high hopes for WebDriver as part of selenium 2 once it stabilizes. While using selenium we've had to Monkey Patch the python driver to make it more pythonic. Wrapping the python-selenium driver so it changes:

```
selenium.doCommand('waitForElementPresent', 'selector')
```

into:

```
selenium.wait_for_element_present('selector')
```

You can then use nose and selenium to run QUnit http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit if you want to just test base javascript functions that don't necessarily change the DOM.

Example selenium integration:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.test_url = "http://your_domain"
    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox3", self.test_url)
    self.selenium.start()

def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. How about using PyUnit for unit testing python code.

Comment: There shouldn't be a lot of difference between using PyUnit and Nose to execute your other javascript tests. They are very similar, launching and using selenium would happen in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try nose http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/

Comment: I am doing some RND, also looking into selenium IDE. But still havent figured out which one would be good nad appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://replit.com its a web based IDE for python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).